# Problems with solid fieldset border in IE8

Tags: css, fieldset

I wish to style my fieldsets so that they have a solid border.

So I styled it like this...

```
fieldset {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid orange;
    border-width: 30px 1px 1px 1px;
}

fieldset legend {
    background-color: orange;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* uncomment line below for IE8 */
    /* margin-top: -50px; */
}
```

And it looks like this on most browsers (IE9, Chrome, FF14) ...

[image: how it should look]

I have problems getting this to work on IE8. I have added a -ve margin to align the legend properly but there are still 2 vertical white bars each side of the legend that I cant get rid of...

[image: on MSIE8]

Fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/NmwuC/

Any ideas how to get rid of the white bars on IE8 (I dont care about IE7, IE6 etc)?

(By the way, the HTML is generated by the Drupal framework so I'd prefer a solution that doesnt involve changing the HTML.)

Comment: Try this `*{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: @Bondye - thanks, but didnt work I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked it and changed for IE8. Check http://jsfiddle.net/NmwuC/16/

This is only for IE8.

Comment: Thanks @rain. Close, but I'm getting an extra artefact above the bar on the RHS.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot for your result. Then I will check again.

Comment: How it looks for me on IE8: [what I get](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B93lksnTC7_cQnd4bkxTdlFZNk0).

Comment: Check the new jsfiddle link in answer, it should work now.
Let me know if the issue is still there.